# Can't use the JavaScript Console for calling up button classes

Tags: javascript, console

I'm new to JS and I've been trying to automate a button clicker, but before I can do that I have to call buttons correctly.

Let's say I'm on the stackoverflow home page and I want to access the "ask question" button. I right clicked on it and see that the class is `"ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary"`. I'm trying to call it in my code so I do

```
"let btn = document.querySelectorAll(".ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary")"
```

and then press enter. I get `undefined` and then I put `"btn"` into the console and I get `"NodeList[]"` which has a length of 0 which it shouldn't.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Classes have a dot before them.

Comment: I still get a node list of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector('.ws-nowrap.s-btn.s-btn__primary')` will get you what you want.  They are all classes on the same element, they are not nested, so no spaces.